# Filtering DB result based on column value

Tags: php, sql, filter

I want to select users in my SQL database based on an attribute they already add it. This attribute is a link that start by any website domain name.

So what command should i use in PHP that can filter rows based on a chosen domain name? of course disregarding the remaining of the link and considering only the domain name.

Comment: A WHERE clause in your SQL query?

Comment: WHERE looks for the whole value inside a column. I need to look for the value partially i.e. i need to filter the link 'www.domainname123.com/123456' by looking only for 'www.domainname123.com' @Mark

Comment: WHERE isn't limited to an entire column; by using MySQL functions (or LIKE) you can search partially on a column, or even on multiple columns via CONCAT(). Here you can use WHERE with a [regex](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/regexp.html) to isolate the domain, or using LIKE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use PHP as a "one size fits all tool" but **it's not the right tool for this job**. Your database engine would handle such task much more efficiently. Besides, it will save you the overkill of transfering unfiltered data you don't need.

From your description, the query should be

```
select user_id, username from users where users.url like '%domain.com%'
```

This will give you only the relevant rows. Then you can use PHP [parse_url](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.parse-url.php) function to grab just the host and discard the rest.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a WHERE clause in your query to the database:

```
    SELECT id, username, other_field FROM your_table WHERE domain LIKE '%your_domain_variable%'
```

That will return the users where the domain field in the table is like whatever domain is supplied in the domain variable you supply.